# How to concatenate 2 Arrays based on templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to get familiar with C++ templates. I need to write a template of function that concatenates 2 arrays:

```
template<typename T, int Size>
class Array
{
public:
    void push(int i, const T& t) { _elem[i] = t; }
private:
    T _elem[Size];
};
```

For example I have 2 arrays:

```
Array<int,3> a1;
Array<int,4> a2;
```

I don't know how to write this function, that will return

```
Array<int,7>.
```

How should header of this function look like?

Answer (score 2):

You should try it like this:

```
template<typename T, int A, int B>
Array<T, A+B> concatenate(Array<T, A> first, Array<T, B> second) 
{
    Array<T, A+B> result;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < A; ++idx) {
        result.push(idx, first[idx]);
    }
    for (int idx = 0; idx < B; ++idx) {
        result.push(idx+A, second[idx]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what those `typename`'s are for.

Comment: @duselbaer, the return type and the two input types are different, so you'd need to template the function allowing for type T and two sizes.

Comment: The typenames are necessary to tell the compiler this is a dependant type. Visual Studio will not complain of the typenames are missing - but GCC will. http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html

Comment: @juanchopanza: That's what I did - I don't understand your comment?

Comment: @dusel: That's what typename does, sure, but you have no dependent types. That would be something like `Array<T, A>::now_dependent`.

Comment: @duselbaer maybe it was a formatting problem. When I first looked at your answer, it looked nothing like the current one :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, as a free-function outside the class:

```
template <typename T, int SizeA, int SizeB>
Array<T, SizeA + SizeB> join(const Array<T, SizeA>& first,
                                const Array<T, SizeB>& second)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

For what it's worth, you should probably use `std::size_t` from `<cstddef>` instead of `int`.